# Python Numpy Array Mult Combinations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I have a 1 by N and a N by 1 array.

As for Lin All We know that when those two are multiplied we get a 1 by 1 or a value.

N is the value we want. But I want to randomly generate the first array while the second array has weights. This is for a Operations Research Problem.

[0th random, 1st random, N-1th random] * [ [0], [1], [2], ..., [N-1] ]

My code is like this:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
N = 4
winner = 0
A = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(N-1), repeat = N-1)))
V_weights = np.arange(1, N, 1).reshape(N-1,1)
for array in A:
    if array.dot(V_weights) == N:
        # print(array)
        # print(V_weights)
        # print(array.dot(V_weights))
        winner += 1
print(winner)
```

I want the while loop to end once all the combinations have come through. Ideally the correct amount of iterations.

For example: I have 4 types of logs 1 lb, 2 lb, 3lb, 4lb and Need a total amount of wood (say 10 lb)

That would give me several combinations of wood types:

10 1lb
3 1lb, 2 2 lb, 1 3 lb
Also 
2 lb, 1 3lb, 1 5lb

Etc.

Thus I figured I would generate random arrays until I got all operations.

Sorry if this is a bit confusing - happy to edit unless someone needs a faster easier way.

Comment: How do you break out of the loop?  Is each call to `random.choice` supposed to be independent?

Comment: @hpaulj sry edited it. When the value hits the value I want. But I want all combinations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the set of calls to the choice:

```
In [27]: np.random.choice(range(4), size=(1,3), replace=False)
Out[27]: array([[1, 2, 3]])
In [28]: np.random.choice(range(4), size=(1,3), replace=False)
Out[28]: array([[2, 1, 3]])
In [29]: np.random.choice(range(4), size=(1,3), replace=False)
Out[29]: array([[1, 2, 0]])
In [30]: np.random.choice(range(4), size=(1,3), replace=False)
Out[30]: array([[1, 3, 2]])
In [31]: np.random.choice(range(4), size=(1,3), replace=False)
Out[31]: array([[2, 3, 0]])
In [32]: np.random.choice(range(4), size=(1,3), replace=False)
Out[32]: array([[1, 3, 2]])
```

Notice that [1,3,2] came up twice.

This produces all length 3 permutations from this range (not in a random order - though the list could be shuffled)

```
In [33]: import itertools
In [34]: itertools.permutations?
Init signature: itertools.permutations(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:     
permutations(iterable[, r]) --> permutations object

Return successive r-length permutations of elements in the iterable.

permutations(range(3), 2) --> (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1)
Type:           type
In [35]: itertools.permutations(range(4), 3)
Out[35]: <itertools.permutations at 0xaf7193bc>
In [36]: list(_)
Out[36]: 
[(0, 1, 2),
 (0, 1, 3),
 ...
 (3, 2, 1)]
```

The weighted values of those permutations:

```
In [38]: wgts = np.arange(1, 4)
In [39]: A = np.array(list(itertools.permutations(range(4),3)))
In [40]: A.shape
Out[40]: (24, 3)
In [41]: wgts
Out[41]: array([1, 2, 3])
In [42]: A.dot(wgts)
Out[42]: 
array([ 8, 11,  7, 13,  9, 12,  7, 10,  5, 14,  7, 13,  5, 11,  4, 13,  8,
       11,  6,  9,  5, 11,  7, 10])
```

---

Based on your comment I realize you are sampling with replacement.  Here's a quick bruteforce way of doing such as search

Generate a bunch of test values.  Since this is with replacement on each row, we can generate many rows with just one call to `choice`:

```
In [55]: A = np.random.choice(range(4), size=(100,3), replace=True)
In [56]: A
Out[56]: 
array([[3, 1, 1],
       [0, 3, 0],
       [1, 3, 2],
       [3, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 2],
       [0, 3, 2],
       ...
       [3, 0, 3]])
```

As before take the weighted sum:

```
In [57]: wgts = np.arange(1, 4)
In [58]: A.dot(wgts)
Out[58]: 
array([ 8,  6, 13,  8,  8, 12,  5, 10,  9, 12,  9,  9,  7,  9,  0,  4,  3,
        6, 10,  8,  7,  2,  3, 14, 11,  7,  1,  7,  2,  5, 11,  3, 13, 12,
        7,  9,  4, 15,  1,  7,  7,  9, 10,  7,  9, 11, 14,  3, 13, 11,  2,
        9,  9,  2, 11, 16,  4, 10, 13,  9, 11,  8, 10,  5,  7,  8, 13, 15,
       11,  9, 13,  7,  6,  9,  5, 12,  9, 11,  6,  3,  0,  0,  9,  7, 11,
        0, 12,  9,  7,  7,  3,  7, 13,  3,  9,  5, 14,  1, 16, 12])
```

And find the indices where that sum has the target value:

```
In [59]: np.where(_==4)
Out[59]: (array([15, 36, 56], dtype=int32),)
In [60]: A[_]
Out[60]: 
array([[2, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [0, 2, 0]])
```

For `N=5`:

```
In [61]: A = np.random.choice(range(5), size=(100,4), replace=True)
In [62]: A.dot(np.arange(1,5))
Out[62]: 
array([29, 20,... 23])
In [63]: np.where(_==5)
Out[63]: (array([], dtype=int32),)
```

This sample wasn't big enough, lets try a larger one:

```
In [64]: A = np.random.choice(range(5), size=(500,4), replace=True)
In [65]: A.dot(np.arange(1,5))
Out[65]: 
array([23,  8, 17, ...18])
In [66]: np.where(_==5)
Out[66]: (array([ 58, 267, 443], dtype=int32),)
In [67]: A[_]
Out[67]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 0],
       [3, 1, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 1, 0]])
```

---

`itertools.product` can be used to general all combinations

```
In [71]: A = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(4),repeat=3)))
In [72]: A.shape
Out[72]: (64, 3)
In [73]: x = A.dot(np.arange(1,4))
In [74]: A[x==4]
Out[74]: 
array([[0, 2, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [2, 1, 0]])
```

for N=5:

```
In [75]: A = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(5),repeat=4)))
In [76]: A.shape
Out[76]: (625, 4)
In [77]: x = A.dot(np.arange(1,5))
In [78]: A[x==5]
Out[78]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 0, 0],
       [2, 0, 1, 0],
       [3, 1, 0, 0]])
```

---

To do the search iteratively I'd use `product` as a generator:

```
In [100]: g = itertools.product(range(5), repeat=4)
In [101]: for cnt, row in enumerate(g):
     ...:     if np.arange(1,5).dot(row)==5:
     ...:         print(cnt, row)
     ...: 
     ...:     
30 (0, 1, 1, 0)
126 (1, 0, 0, 1)
175 (1, 2, 0, 0)
255 (2, 0, 1, 0)
400 (3, 1, 0, 0)
```

Or to just find the first:

```
In [102]: g = itertools.product(range(5), repeat=4)
In [103]: for cnt, row in enumerate(g):
     ...:     if np.arange(1,5).dot(row)==5:
     ...:         print(cnt, row)
     ...:         break
     ...:     
30 (0, 1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: So I've followed ur answer.

Comment: For an N of 5 - I should get [3, 1, 0, 0]*[[1], [2], [3], [4]] and [0, 1, 1, 0]*[[1], [2], [3], [4]] but I don't.

Comment: My `permutations` code acts like the `choice` with `replace=False`.  Neither produces duplicates like [3,1,0,0].

Comment: I fixed it. was an issue with range. Super slow for higher numbers.

Comment: Another approach is to iterate on the `product` generator, without the intermediate `A` array.

Comment: I was essentially trying to solve Euler's problem I realize with Lin Alg to find all the possibilities. https://projecteuler.net/problem=31

Comment: @Dasman Please do your math and understand that a brute force approach won't work with ProjectEuler's problem 31.

Comment: @gboffi - Is it because the same arrays would constantly be regenerated? I am told to avoid redoing computations - look into dynamic programming.